# LINQ to Datatable Group By

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

I have a query that returns 3 columns of data.

```
Country | Religion | Population
--------------------------------
US | Christianity | 80000000
US | Islam | 1000000
US | Judaism | 5000000
China | Buddhism | 100000000
China | Christianity | 2345737
```

and so on.

I need to show this data by country. The JSON object will look like

```
[ { "Country" : "US", 
             {
                "Christianity" : 80000000, 
                "Islam": 1000000, 
                "Judaism": 5000000 
             }
      },
      { "Country" : "China", 
             {
                "Buddhism " : 100000000, 
                "Christianity ": 2345737
             }
      }
   ]
```

What's the best way to do this? Get the data into a datatable and use LINQ to query it (if yes then how?)

Or maybe create a Dictionary>. But I am confused as to how to populate the data.

Maybe create a class with Country, Dictionary and return an array of this class.

Thanks.

Comment: whats stopping you from simply grouping in the query?

Comment: The query is already grouped by country in the inner loop. How will the output of the query look like according to you? I am not very clear how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: The correct answer is never datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can group the data using [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq).

You can use something like this:

```
var grouped = from d in sampleData
                group d by d.Country
                into g
                select new {
                         Country = g.Key,
                         Data = g.Select(i => new {
                                             Religion = i.Religion,
                                             Population = i.Population
                                         })
                          };
```

However once it serialized into JSON it will not look exactly the same.

Comment: It's not valid JSON to begin with ;-)  Property names can't end with a space.  You can't have unnamed properties.

Comment: @RobertMcKee, you're right there's no property to hold the inner data of each group.

Comment: sampleData is a datatable? Also I didn't understand what Robert is saying about this not being a valid JSon. Which property is ending with a space?

Comment: Just run your sample JSON through jsonlint.com, But in order to the sample JSON to be valid you will need a property to hold the groups like **Data** in the following sample. `{
        "Country": "China",
        "Data": {
            "Buddhism ": 100000000,
            "Christianity ": 2345737
        }
    }`